Rollbar Ruby, how to send a custom error and adding an exception and a custom message
Following the Rollbar documentation I see I can send a custom error with an exception like this:
Rollbar.error(exception)

But I would like to add a custom message to the Rollbar occurrence like:
Rollbar.error(exception, "My custom message")

In the error() method documentation, it says that it accepts args*, but it is not said in what order I can send them.

Making my own experiments, I see Rollbar.error() accepts the arguments in any order:
Rollbar.error(exception, "My custom message")
Rollbar.error("My custom message", exception)

